# Safely convert a Pandas datetime Series to Int64 epoch timestamp, preserving nulls

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, unix-timestamp

Consider a datetime-dtype Series containing some null values:

```py
import pandas as pd

t = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', freq='4H').to_series('t')
t.iat[2] = None
```

```
2022-01-01 00:00:00   2022-01-01 00:00:00
2022-01-01 04:00:00   2022-01-01 04:00:00
2022-01-01 08:00:00                   NaT
2022-01-01 12:00:00   2022-01-01 12:00:00
2022-01-01 16:00:00   2022-01-01 16:00:00
2022-01-01 20:00:00   2022-01-01 20:00:00
2022-01-02 00:00:00   2022-01-02 00:00:00
Freq: 4H, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The `dtype` of this Series is `<M8[ns]`. As far as I understand, this means that the underlying data is physically stored as 64-bit integers representing nanoseconds since the start of the Unix epoch ([`numpy.datetime64`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.datetime64)). However I don't know how `NaT` is represented.

I would like to obtain an integer timestamp representing the number of nanoseconds since the start of the Unix epoch, with null values wherever there was an `NaT` in the data. Therefore it seems like I should be able to somehow check the precision of the timestamp data type, extract the raw seconds, and then scale up or down as needed to obtain nanoseconds.

Expected output:

```
2022-01-01 00:00:00    1640995200000000000
2022-01-01 04:00:00    1641009600000000000
2022-01-01 08:00:00                   <NA>
2022-01-01 12:00:00    1641038400000000000
2022-01-01 16:00:00    1641052800000000000
2022-01-01 20:00:00    1641067200000000000
2022-01-02 00:00:00    1641081600000000000
Freq: 4H, dtype: Int64
```

Things that did not work:

```py
t.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())  # datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to IntegerDtype`
t.astype(float).astype(pd.Int64Dtype())  # Cannot cast DatetimeArray to dtype float64
t.map(lambda t: t.timestamp()).astype(pd.Int64Dtype())  # NaTType does not support timestamp
t.map(lambda t: t.timestamp(), na_action='ignore').astype(pd.Int64Dtype())  # 'values' contains non-numeric NA NaT
```

Notably the `.timestamp` logic gets hung up on the `NaT`, which I don't know how to cleanly convert to the "null-aware" `Int64Dtype`.

Something that did work, but is very ugly:

```py
((t - pd.Timestamp(1970, 1, 1)).dt.total_seconds() * 1e09).astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: @FObersteiner That's true for the Numpy native `int64` type, but Pandas in the last few years introduced `Int64Dtype()` which _does_ support its own null value representation. Internally it uses the same Arrow memory format that is used by Parquet, Polars, et al. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html. The "Expected output" I provided in my question is verbatim output from the "Something that did work" code, and that `<NA>` value is a true "null" value, analogous to R `NA` or SQL `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I don't think there is a good way to do that. Another approach:

```
>>> t.view(np.int64).astype(pd.Int64Dtype()).replace(np.iinfo(np.int64).min, pd.NA)

0    1640995200000000000
1    1641009600000000000
2                   <NA>
3    1641038400000000000
4    1641052800000000000
5    1641067200000000000
6    1641081600000000000
Name: t, dtype: Int64

# Without replace(...)
>>> t.view(np.int64).astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
0     1640995200000000000
1     1641009600000000000
2    -9223372036854775808
3     1641038400000000000
4     1641052800000000000
5     1641067200000000000
6     1641081600000000000
Name: t, dtype: Int64
```

---

What you expect is unclear for me. Maybe you can use `numpy`:

```
ts = t.values.astype(float)
dti = pd.to_datetime(ts)
```

```
>>> ts
array([ 1.64099520e+18,  1.64100960e+18, -9.22337204e+18,  1.64103840e+18,
        1.64105280e+18,  1.64106720e+18,  1.64108160e+18])

>>> dti
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-01 04:00:00',
                               'NaT', '2022-01-01 12:00:00',
               '2022-01-01 16:00:00', '2022-01-01 20:00:00',
               '2022-01-02 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

>>> t
0   2022-01-01 00:00:00
1   2022-01-01 04:00:00
2                   NaT
3   2022-01-01 12:00:00
4   2022-01-01 16:00:00
5   2022-01-01 20:00:00
6   2022-01-02 00:00:00
Name: t, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I am not asking about constructing datetime data. I added my expected output to my question.

Comment: I see, thanks. Yes I think that does answer the question, but I'll hold off for a bit to see if other answers come in. I would also want to check the `dtype` somehow to verify that the underlying storage frequency is in fact nanoseconds.